# How do I block ads from Google?

Tags: google-adsense

OK I have blocked "Evony Online" and other such annoying stuff using the competitive ad filter. But I am now getting these exasperating flash adverts from Google themselves for "Google Translate".

How do I block adsense ads from Google? I tried putting google.com and google.co.* into the competitive ad filter but it doesn't seem to work.

*(Please note: If you don't know what the words **competitive ad filter** mean, you won't know the answer to this question.)*

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://superuser.com/

Comment: @vmarquez: no it doesn't. This is about "adsense" and is clearly labelled as such.

Comment: @Kinopiko: You are right. My mistake. I may have read the question without too much care :S

Comment: OK sorry I was a bit of a bad mood this morning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried putting google.com and google.co.* into the competitive ad filter but it doesn't seem to work.

The adsense URI is:

```
googlesyndication.com
```

Comment: Thanks, I've already added it. Will be checking back to make sure they've gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a file at http://pgl.yoyo.org/as/#foursteps which contains hundreds of ad server's url's and get rid of almost all advertisements while browsing. You need to copy paste it in your windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts file.

Advantages of pasting all those urls:
 -

- Those ads will not be able to
  distract you
- Browser will be faster as all that javascript ads load from remote
  server
- You save some unnecessary bandwidth

I've had a new discovery. Even after adding all those url Chrome is using some trick to show through doubleclick.net ads! That's bad part of Google which is leveraging Chrome to it's advantage.

Comment: No, this is about blocking ads on your website.